# How do I retrieve XML tags by tag attribute

Tags: xml

I'm struggling with some XML in javascript, how can i select only tags with certain attribute values?

The following example from [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/tryit.asp?filename=try_xpath_select_pricenodes_text) uses this [xml file](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

And then the following script gets and prints on a new line all the text from the price tags.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadXMLDoc(dname){
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else{
                xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
            xhttp.send("");
            return xhttp.responseXML;
        }
        //getting the xml into a var to parse       
        xml=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");


        //the path in question
        path="/bookstore/book/price/text()"   ////how can i change this to only select the prices of the books where the category="COOKING" ?


        // code for IE
        if (window.ActiveXObject){
            var nodes=xml.selectNodes(path);

            for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
                {
                    document.write(nodes[i].nodeValue);
                    document.write("<br />");
                }
        }
        // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument){
            var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null);
            var result=nodes.iterateNext();

            while (result)
                {
                    document.write(result.nodeValue + "<br />");
                    result=nodes.iterateNext();
                }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to change the path so that the script will only print out the text of the prices tag where parent tag 'book' has a category attribute of 'COOKING'  (i put a comment in the script where the current path is that I think i need to change, but i can't find out how)?

I'm really stuck and can't seem to find out how to get it. Any help would awesome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your path you need to put for instance `//bookName/[@CATEGORY = COOKING]` the @ is where it looks at the attribute.  Hope this helps.